# Page has crashed: Error: Page crashed![PUPPETEER] on docker

Tags: docker, socket.io, puppeteer

I am running puppeteer on docker the image builds successfully, also the container is running successfully but I having the error below when opening socket connection with the docker container:

```
[2021-08-05 09:25:29.906] [ERROR] browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/src/ChromePage.js - Page has crashed: Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:290:28)
    at Page.client.on (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:176:57)
    at slice.map (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)
    at CDPSession.emit (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:225:18)
    at Connection._onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:101:25)
    at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WebSocketTransport.js:13:32)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:290:28)
    at Page.client.on (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:176:57)
    at slice.map (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)
    at CDPSession.emit (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:225:18)
    at Connection._onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:101:25)
    at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WebSocketTransport.js:13:32)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/chrome/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
(node:200) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
```

I tried to increase the memory when running the docker container like below but I still continue to have the same error.

```
docker run --shm-size 2GB ...

docker run --shm-size 10GB ...

docker run --shm-size 50GB ...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Below is the top result from inside container:
[image]